# Como capturar un Error MalformedJsonException

Tags: java, json

estoy intentando capturar un error del tipo MalformedJsonException de la librería gson versión 2.8.5.

```
  try {
            String json = "{ \"name\": \"prueba\", \"java\": true}}";
            JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
            System.out.println(jsonObject.get("name"));
        }catch(MalformedJsonException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

El problema es que cuando intento usar la clase MalformedJsonException como catch sale el siguiente error.

> Unreachable catch block for MalformedJsonException. This exception is
>   never thrown from the try statement body.

¿Hay alguna forma de capturar este tipo de error cuando tienen este problema?

Comment: Lo que te dice al compilar es que no tiene sentido que captures esa `Exception` ya que nunca se lanzara esa excepción en tu bloque `try`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La excepción que tienes que capturar es `JsonSyntaxException`

Esta excepción es la que lanza el método parse (entre otros métodos) para indicar que el JSON no es válido:

- [Método
  parse](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html#parse-java.lang.String-)

También puedes controlar con el método setLenient de JsonReader cómo de estricto quieres que se parsee ese JSON:

- [Método
  setLenient](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html#setLenient-boolean-)

El compilador no te está obligando a capturarla porque esta clase hereda de RuntimeException, pero puedes (y deberías capturarla) para tratar el caso de JSON mal formado.

Comment: Cuando dices "puedes y debes capturarla" te refieres a la Excepción que comentas que es la que realmente lanza el parse ¿no? Ya que la excepción que el OP comenta no se lanzará ¿no?

Comment: Si, la excepción que comenta OP (MalformedJsonException) no se lanza para los métodos que ha puesto en la pregunta. Para la excepcion JsonSyntaxException que es de runtime, el compilador no te obliga, pero digo que "debe" capturarla porque es un tipo de error frecuente y no se puede asumir que el JSON va a estar siempre bien formado. Lo voy a cambiar por "deberías" para evitar confusión

Answer (score 0):

El bloque de `catch` tiene que capturar las excepciones que se lanzan dentro del bloque `try`, no puede capturar una excepción que tu código no está lanzando

```
try {
    //Código que lanza la excepcionA
    throw new ExceptionA("Soy la excepcion Alpha!");
}
catch(ExceptionA e) {
    //do something to handle the exception, e.g.
    System.out.println("Message: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Y tu estas intentando capturar una excepción que nunca se lanza en tu bloque de código try:

```
try {
    //Código que lanza la excepcionB
    throw new ExceptionB("Soy la excepcion  Bravo!");
}
catch(ExceptionA e) {
    System.out.println("Message: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Efectivamente el `.parse()`no lanza la excepción `MalformedJsonException` como comenta @Ordago, podeis ver la excepcion que realmente hay que capturar en su respuesta:
[Respuesta de Ordago](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/295001/128699)

---

[Respuesta Original en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613423/exception-is-never-thrown-in-body-of-corresponding-try-statement) del usuario [Christian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934396/christian)

Comment: Pero hace que me pregunte, ¿Como es posible que no esté lanzando la excepción, si en el código de error aparece?. ¿Tal vez sea un Subtipo de la Exceptión que realmente lanza?. Editaré mi pregunta para mostrar el error sin Try Catch. Olvidalo ordago ha respondido a mi pregunta.

Comment: Como bien comenta Ordago, la excepción que tienes que capturar es otra. Si te ha servido su pregunta marcala como aceptada para que quede cerrada la pregunta. Ademas así ganaras reputación y podrás conseguir mas [Privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) como votar las preguntas y respuestas.